# C#,How to convert a list of ParentClass to a list of ChildClass?

Tags: c#

I have a class named PokerPiece and it is Inherit from class Piece.

So, If I can make `List<Piece> pieces =new List<PokerPiece>()` work? If not, how can I make it?

Comment: Just make a list of Pieces instead, a PokerPiece is a Piece also.

Comment: Just use `List<Piece> pieces = new List<Piece>()` where you declared `class Piece : PokerPiece`.

Comment: Actually,I can add PokerPiece item into the List of Piece, But when I get the items from List of Piece, I can't get the attributes were declared in PokerPiece.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are stating is related to Covariant/Contravariant.

```
 IEnumerable<Piece> piece = new List<PokerPiece>();
```

The below link can help you

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: The type for pieces can also be IReadOnlyCollection<Piece> or IReadOnlyList<Piece>

Answer (score 0):

I think you somehow got it the wrong way - normaly you might want something like:

```
var myList =new List<Message> ();

var myChildObject = new ChildMessage();

myList.add(myChildObject)

myList[0] as ChildMessage == null // should not return null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
List<Piece> pieces = new List<Piece>(new List<PokerPiece>());
```

But you should probably just make

```
List<Piece> pieces = new List<Piece>();
```

Or

```
List<PokerPiece> pieces = new List<PokerPiece>();
```

Comment: But that does the same as new List<Piece>() ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo I agree. But the OP asked for suggestions so I gave one.

Comment: @SirRufo@Guy thanks for your Suggestions. Now I can add child-class-item to the parent-class-List. However, I don't know how to get attributes which were declared in PokerPiece when I get item from List of Piece.

Comment: @XieWeiXuan You need to cast it  `((PokerPiece)pieces[0]).SomeAttribute;`